# How to fix the delay between mouse wheel up and down on the picture box refresh while scaling a rectangle or a shape on the GraphicsPath object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

1.I'm trying to scale a rectangle while a user does mouse up and mouse down on the picture box.
2.After doing 5 mouse wheel up and if you do mouse wheel down the rectangle still keeps scales up(expands).
3.Any solution to it?

```
GraphicsPath path=new GraphicsPath();
private float scale=1.0F;
private bool ActiveWheel=false;
public Form1()
{
    path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(10,10,50,100));
}
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(ActiveWheel)
    {
        ActiveWheel=false;
        ScaleRectangle(e);

    }
else
{
   e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red,path);
}

}
private void PictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ActiveWheel=true;
    scale=Math.Max(scale+Math.Sign(e.Delta)*0.1F,0.1F);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
}
private void ScaleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.Scale(scale,scale,MatrixOrder.Append);
    path.Transform(matrix);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Blue,path);
}
```

Any solution or idea how to scale down or scale up a shape suddenly without a delay in between mouse wheel ups and mouse wheel downs(see 2. if want to see actually o/p).

Comment: Do you want to scale (on a MouseWheel) just the selected Shape (on a MouseDown) or the whole content of the PictureBox? i.e., if you have 2 Shapes, all scale or just the selected one?

Comment: Scaling shape would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust the scale value in the MouseWheel() event, then ScaleTransform() the GRAPHICS surface (not the Path itself) in the Paint() event and draw:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    private float scale = 1.0F;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 100));
        pictureBox1.MouseWheel += PictureBox1_MouseWheel;
        pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void PictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        scale = Math.Max(scale + Math.Sign(e.Delta) * 0.1F, 0.1F);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
    }

}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

> It scales entirely, could you show me how to scale only graphics path
>   object and top, left have to be fixed, meaning without scaling the
>   top, left point?

In that case, translate to the top left point of your rectangle, scale, then translate back to the origin.  Now draw your UNCHANGED rectangle:

```
    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(10, 10);
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-10, -10);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
    }
```

If you have other elements that are being drawn at different positions and/or scales, then you can reset the graphics surface before and after (each "element" can do the same type of thing to position itself and scale itself):

```
    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // possibly other drawing operations

        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(10, 10);
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-10, -10);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

        // possibly other drawing operations

    }
```

This approach is nice as it keeps the original information about your rectangle; the change is simply visual.

Comment: Same logic could be applied the GraphicsPath if you don't want the whole surface to scale.

Comment: It scales entirely, could you show me how to scale only graphics path object and top, left have to be fixed, meaning without scaling the top, left point?